# How open a new page in a new tab from a dialog page?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using apex 21.1. I am building a clinic management system.

scenario: A new patient goes to the secretary to tell him his name, age and other details. The secretary stores their data and record a visit. When the patient goes to the doctor, the doctor diagnosis the patient and write a prescription.

I have a report named VISITS and a form(Edit visit). The report displays patients' visits data and a link to edit the visit data in the form. The report has another column(link) that opens a dialog page(Examine Patient) which has a form for the doctor to store the complaint, diagnosis and other data of the patient and it has an interactive grid for the doctor to enter the prescription details i.e drug, dose, etc... . I've created another page( a report for the prescription that is printed using window.print() after the page is completely loaded and it closes too using window.close() after printing). The doctor should be able to call that prescription report and send it some data after submitting dialog page(Examine Patient) - after processing.

I tried to create a branch(after processing), and submitting the page through dynamic action with Action=submit and writing the code that calls the report page(prescription) in a subsequent action. All those tries did not solve the problem.

This is the code with which I call the new page

```
"apex.navigation.openInNewWindow('f?p=&APP_ID.:10:&APP_SESSION.:::10:P10_EXAMINATION_ID,P10_PRESCRIPTION_TYPE:&P2_ID.,E');"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps generate and open a link, but just set the attribute:

target="_blank"

Setting this attribute in the link means it should open in a new tab.

Comment: The page is opened successfully in a new tab. The problem is that I need to open it after processing to guarantee that all data in the dialog page is submitted to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In the dialog page, create a dynamic action with "When" = Event: "Before Page Submit". Add a true action of type "Execute Javascript Code" with source

```
apex.navigation.openInNewWindow('f?p=&APP_ID.:10:&APP_SESSION.:::10:P10_EXAMINATION_ID,P10_PRESCRIPTION_TYPE:&P2_ID.,E');
```

This worked ok for me.

Comment: The page is opened successfully in a new tab. The problem is that I need to open it after processing to guarantee that all data in the dialog page is submitted to the database.

Comment: You can't invoke a DA after processing - at that pointed the work is happening in the database and you no longer have access to the DOM where the dynamic actions live. What you could do is fire a dynamic action onload of the target page you're branching to.